# xpath: select node closest to root

Tags: xpath

I need select a specific node name closest to (not needly on) root.

**Example:**

```
<root>
    <a>
        <b id="1"></b>
        <b id="2">
            <b id="3"></b>
        </b>
        <c>
            <b id="4"></b>
        </c>
    </a>
</root>
```

It should select `b#1`, `b#2` and `b#4`, but not `b#2`, because it is included inside of another `b` node.

Currently I'm doing that: select all `b`, so check if some of parents is `b`, if yes, discard that. But I do it hardcoded, maybe *xpath* can solve that alone?

Comment: have you got your solution?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, just using **not** + **ancestor**, like:

```
//table[not(ancestor::table)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try below expression-

```
//b[not(.//ancestor::b)]
```

It selects-

```
<b id="1"/>

<b id="4"/>
```

**See live at [here](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/86392351508625621a3b61d8c2caaa9c).**

Comment: Thanks, but it should select `b#2` too.

Comment: Ah! it is working see  at http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/86392351508625621a3b61d8c2caaa9c

Comment: Your quote `It should select b#1, b#2 and b#4, but not b#2,` so does not it mean `b#1` and `b#4`? And hence i tried- Thanks